# ASP.NET without runat="server"

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have to create a simple website using asp.net web forms, but I'm required to not use any server controls i.e. `runat="server"`

I have the following:

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
    <input value="Save" type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void myFunction()
{
    // do something
}
```

I'm currently putting `// do something` in the `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` function, but I would like to call it when the save button is clicked. However I don't know how to do this without using `runat="server"`. Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: Use JavaScript...

Comment: @DavidG - Is that the only way of doing it?

Comment: Whatever you do requires some form of JavaScript, even the `runat=server` controls.

Comment: Using webforms but saying no `runat="server"` is like saying go kayaking, but no paddles. It sounds more like you should be using ASP.NET MVC

Comment: @DavidG - Fair enough. Thank you

Comment: @Jamiec - It doesn't make sense to me either, but that's what I've been asked to do.

Comment: @linkzip any reason given? If someone is paying you to be a programmer, theyre not paying you to be a mindless drone - they should value your technical knowledge.

Comment: @Jamiec nope, they just said no `runat="server"`. I asked several times.

Comment: Then use MVC. There are no runat=server at all. If they say "no MVC" and "use webforms without runat=server" you're working for a moron - run, run fast and run now.

Comment: @Jamiec They said no MVC either. At that point I wanted to quit.

Comment: Get out before its too late!

Comment: @Jamiec Best answer right there.

Comment: It's a very strange artificial restriction to place on you here, are you sure that's what was asked?

Comment: @DavidG pretty sure, but that's why I asked on here. I thought maybe I was missing the point.

Comment: Maybe go back and ask if it was actually `viewstate` that they were worried about. That problem *can* be worked around - you dont need viewstate to execute a button click action.

Comment: there is absolutely 0 reason to use webform over MVC if you cant do runat server. time to look for your next job

Answer (score 2):

The **real answer** to this question is in the comment:

> Using `webforms` but saying no `runat="server"` is like saying go kayaking, but no paddles. It sounds more like you should be using ASP.NET MVC

I'll add [ASP.Net Web Pages](https://www.asp.net/web-pages) as well for getting things done quickly (note: this **doesn't** mean `ASP.Net Web Pages` are *only* for "simple" sites - you can do whatever you want with it).

> I have to create a simple website using `asp.net web forms`

But since it "has to" be `WebForms` it's still *doable*. Is it *advisable?* **nope** - particularly with aforementioned options as well as other comments on `SPA`/`Javascript`/`XHR`.

End of day, **it's still `HTTP Requests, and Responses`**, so standard HTML form inputs and such work just like in any other "framework":

- the "front end" (well, `Page` is technically a `control` but we're sticking to `WebForms` so this will be the only "server control"):
  `NoServerControls.aspx`

  ```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NoServerControls.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebForms.NoServerControls" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
      <title>Humor Me Batman</title>
  </head>
      <body>
          <form method="post">
              <input type="text" name="wtf"/>
              <input type="submit" value="Batman"/>
          </form>

          <h1>It's "classic ASP" Batman! <%= echo %></h1>
     </body>
  </html>
  ```
- the "back end" (`NoServerControls.aspx.cs` code behind)

  ```
  public partial class NoServerControls : System.Web.UI.Page
  {

      public string echo { get; set; }

      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          //Trivial example: skipping all validation checks
          //It's either a GET or POST end of day
          if (Request.RequestType == "POST")
          {
              //Do something with data, just echoing it here
              echo = Request["wtf"];
          }

      }
  }
  ```

Hth.

Batman :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a working test project on this please refer this...

```
    <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="custid" class="form-control custname" name="fullname" required />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Designation </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="loading" class="form-control loading">
                            <option value="0">Select </option>
                            <option value="HR">HR </option>
                            <option value="Engg">Engg </option>
                            <option value="Doctor">Doctor </option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mobile No. </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="mobile" class="form-control mobile" onkeypress="return event.charCode >=48 && event.charCode <= 57" name="fullname" required />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email Id </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="emailid" class="form-control emailid" name="fullname" required />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" id="btn">
                        <button type="button" onsubmit="return validateForm()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btn').click(function () {
                var CustNamevalidate = $('.custname').val();
                if (CustNamevalidate != '') {
                    Name = $(".custname").val();
                    Loading = $(".loading").val();
                    Mobile = $(".mobile").val();
                    EmailId = $(".emailid").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "test.aspx/Complextype",
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            Nam: Name, Loadin: Loading, Mobil: Mobile, EmailI: EmailId
                        }),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        datatype: "json"
                    }).done(function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                    })
                }
                else {
                    alert('Please Enter Customer Name');
                }
            });
        });



    </script>
```

Code Behind WEB MEthod

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string Complextype(string Nam, string Loadin, string Mobil, string EmailI)
    {
        string Qtets = "Details are : Name =" + Nam + " And Designation is =" + Loadin + " And Mobileno=" + Mobil + " And EmailI=" + EmailI;
        //  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "test", "<script>alert('Sorry This Category Name Already Exist.');</script>", false);

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constr"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_add_upd_emptb", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", Nam);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpNo", Mobil);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Desig", Loadin);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", EmailI);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 0);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                con.Open();
            }
        }
        //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constr"].ConnectionString);
        //{
        //}

        return Qtets;
    }
```

you Can not call Function Directly if you are not using server controls for function to be called you need to have Web service with static function.